# How can I make a connection between Azure-Dev Ops and microstrategy?

Tags: azure-devops, microstrategy

I have some data present on Azure-DevOps which is constantly updated. To get the updated data, I have to create a dashboard which I do through power BI. The problem with power BI is that I'm unable to share the created dashboard with the rest of my colleagues due to the unavailability of Power BI at the enterprise level. At the enterprise level, we have access to MicroStrategy but it doesn't provide a connection to Azure-DevOps. Hence, through the Power BI dashboard, I am forced to create an excel file which I have to refresh and then feed to MicroStrategy so that I can get a dashboard on MicroStrategy. 
Is there a way I can connect MicroStrategy to Azure-DevOps or somehow eliminate the manual work involved?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make a connection between Azure-Dev Ops and microstrategy?

For this issue , I am afraid that it is currently not supported to connect azure devops with microstrategy . I didn't find any way to do this .

You could submit a feature request in our [Develop Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion. Sorry for any inconvenience.

At present, there seems to be no better way except using Excel Services to pull data from the azure devops data warehouse to microstrategy. This is similar to create Excel based charts and host them on SharePoint sites.

You can refer to this [Displaying Excel Reports on SharePoint sites will continue to work](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/the-future-of-our-tfs-sharepoint-integration/) part of the docs.

Comment: Is there any indirect way through which I can pull the data?

Comment: Hi,Rithwik sorry for the late response, as far as I know using Excel Services to pull data from the azure devops data warehouse to microstrategy is the only way I can think of, this is similar to create Excel based charts and host them on SharePoint sites